# Any drawback or issue when fetching data from function body instead of useEffect(fn,[])?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I usually fetch data with `useEffect` in my react apps. Something similar to:

```
function SomeComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => setData(json))
  }, []);
}
```

I want this code to run only when component mounts, this is why I have the `[]` dependency.

Today I stumbled across code from another person that does it like this:

```
function SomeComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => setData(json))
}
```

No useEffect at all, just fetching data right below use state. Seems like it works.

Here is a code sandbox with both ways to do it: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-lumiere-kwzn6?file=/src/App.js

My question is: is this pattern as good as the useEffect(fn,[])?

- If it's good, then why almost everybody out there uses the useEffect hook to fetch when component mounts?
- If it's not good, then why? What's the drawback?

Comment: Without useEffect you will fetch the data on literally every render, which will in turn rerender the component and fetch the data again ad infinitum. Can you see how long it takes for your sandbox to open? That's because you're fetching the data an inifinity amount of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your requirements.

There's nothing wrong making API request outside useEffect. But it should be done in some other function or it will cause the request to go on every re-render (maybe **infinite**).

Requests that fetch data or send some info at the time of initialization of the component is supposed to be made in componentDidMount/useEffect in order to "write" data in your component.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment @ritaj and the answer @Dario.

After reading your messages, I changed the example (https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-lumiere-kwzn6?file=/src/App.js) so that it logs a message to the console when it does a fetch, and, you're right, we can see an infinite loop for the component that does the fetch outside `useEffect`.

So the answer to my question is: yes, there is a problem fetching data out of useEffect because that would create an infinite loop: fetch causes render, render causes fetch, etc...